# How do I add an opacity to the background color css attribute using a fluent ui color?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

So I am trying to add an opacity to a background color but the specific background color I am using is coming from the fluent UI library, thus using Design Tokens.

I know normally, I can add opacity to a background color like this

```
background-color: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)"
```

But in my application the background color is set as follows

```
import tokens from "fluent ui library here"

export const useStyles = makeStyles({
backgroundColor: tokens.colorNeutralBackground2
)}
```

Does anyone know how I can add opacity to this attribute while using the design token?

Comment: when I console log tokens.colorNeutralBackground2, it logs this: var(--colorNeutralBackground2)

Comment: What is import tokens from "fluent ui library here" ? Can you provide regular path ?

Answer (score 0):

assuming colorNeutralBackground2 is a string you can try this:

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles({
  backgroundColor: `rgba(${tokens.colorNeutralBackground2}, 0.5)`,
});
```

Comment: hmm I already tried that, and didn't do anything. Also looks like the colorNeutralBackground2 is type "any"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know does it works, but how about using

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles({
  backgroundColor: `${tokens.colorNeutralBackground2}${percent}`
});
```

like :
#000000/00 <- transparent
#000000/90 <-opacity 0.9

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution with color-mix. I tried it only in one situation yet, so i do not know if if works in all situations:

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles({
  backgroundColor: `color-mix(in srgb, ${tokens.colorNeutralBackground2} 50%, transparent)`,
});
```

Here is a link to the color-mix:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value/color-mix